# Можно ли использовать старое api для работы с камерой в новых версиях android 21+

Tags: java, android, камера

Создавал приложение для работы с камерой и тестировал работу на android API 17 все хорош работает. Решил включить на API 25, а там оно на камеру ругается.

Можно ли как то использовать старую камеру android.hardware.Camera в новых версиях android api 21+?

Comment: а может просто с правами проблема? Всё же 23 API рантайм пермишен и так далее.

Comment: да проблема была в правах, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В андроид 6.0 и выше (`api 23`) запрос прав на использование камеры и не [только](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview), происходит непосредственно во время выполнения программы. Вы можете реализовать запрос в методе `onCreate` главной активити или в методе запуска камеры. Для `api < 23` разрешения вы прописываете как и раньше в файле манифеста, а в коде делаете условие, что если приложение установлено на устройство `api >= 23` чтобы был вызван запрос на получение прав. Подробнее можете почитать в [официальной](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java) документации.